# Not getting friends list in google plus android

Tags: android, google-plus

I want to get user circle's list of visible friends name and email address with Google Plus.

I have done following code and tried with 4 to 5 phone but in all I am getting zero list

```
class MainActivity extends Activity implements ConnectionCallbacks,
        OnConnectionFailedListener, ResultCallback<People.LoadPeopleResult> {

    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 22;

    private static final String TAG = null;

    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    private boolean mIntentInProgress;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this).addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .build();
    }

    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();

        if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle arg0) {
        System.out.println("onConnected");

        Plus.PeopleApi.loadVisible(mGoogleApiClient, null).setResultCallback(
                this);

    }
    @Override
    public void onResult(LoadPeopleResult peopleData) {
        System.out.println("onResult");
        if (peopleData.getStatus().getStatusCode() == CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS) {
            PersonBuffer personBuffer = peopleData.getPersonBuffer();
            try {
                System.out.println("PersonBuffer : - "
                        + personBuffer.getCount()); <=======HERE I AM GETTING ALWAYS 0
                int count = personBuffer.getCount();
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Display name: "
                            + personBuffer.get(i).getDisplayName());
                }
            } finally {
                personBuffer.close();
            }
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG,
                    "Error requesting visible circles: "
                            + peopleData.getStatus());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
```

Comment: Have you solved issue ?

Answer (score 3):

Please check the following cases below

1. **On the Consent Screen, you don't select circle which allow to see in your app**

   1.1 When the consent screen is showing after login to google+ in your app, 
   Click on the first sentence 'Know your basic profile info and list of people in your circle'

   1.2 Be sure that you select 'All circles', or any non-empty circle
2. **Your google+ account was set disallow your app to see the people in circle**

   2.1 Open Google+ app

   2.2 Select 'Settings'

   2.3 In the 'Account Settings' section, Select your account

   2.4 Select 'Apps with Google+ Sign-in'

   2.5 Select 'All apps & devices'

   2.6 Select your app

   2.7 In the 'This app can see these people', Be sure that it select 'All circles' or any non-empty circle.

   2.8 For more detail, see the 'Change your Google+ Sign-In settings', In the 'Manage who in your circles the app can view' section in link below

   https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2980770?hl=en

Comment: @Bass Pj, After 5 hours R&D I got your answer, it's done. Thanks a lot man. :)